# How to find the probability of finding quantum particles within a certain region

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, phase-space

How to evaluate the probability of finding a quantum particle within a certain radius $R$ from the origin ? I have not been provided with any radial distribution functions, and I'm not sure how to construct one, especially when statistical mechanics is involved.

I've been given $n$ number particles that obey the hamiltonian of the $2$ dimensional quantum harmonic oscillators and I need to find the probability of finding a particle within a distance $R$ from the nucleus. Moreover, the system is connected to a heat bath at temperature $T$.

The hamiltonian is : $$\frac{\hat{p_x}^2}{2m}+\frac{\hat{p_y}^2}{2m}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2(\hat{x}^2+\hat{y}^2)$$

I thought of integrating this over the phase space, between $0$ and $R$, however, I have no idea how to proceed with this.

$$P(R)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dp_xe^{\frac{-{p_x}^2}{2mk_bT}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dp_ye^{\frac{-{p_y}^2}{2mk_bT}}\int_{0}^{R} 2\pi r\,dr\,\,e^{\frac{-m\omega^2{r}^2}{2k_bT}}$$

Is this the correct way to solve this problem ?

In general how should I find the radial distribution function or probability for quantum particles in a canonical ensemble like this ?

Comment: As I understand it, it is a non-interacting problem, so each particle is independent from each other. This also means that the wave-function is factorised (and so the partition function of the whole system). If your particles are bosons the full wavefunction should be symmetric, and for fermions anti-symmetric. I suggest you work with spherical coordinates; then the probability for a single particle would be along the lines you made above, but the probability density is given by the squared modulus of the wave-function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Canonical probability distribution in phase space given by
$$P(p,q)=\frac{1}{\tilde{Z}(T,V,N)}\exp[-\beta H(q,p)]$$
The function $\tilde{Z}$ is given by normalization condition
$$\tilde{Z}(T,V,N)=\int dq\int dp \exp[-\beta H(q,p)]$$
Apart from normalization your one looks good to me. :)